# Google Sheets conditional formatting doesn't apply to the whole range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditionally format a range of cells based on the value of a different cell.  I have selected the range of cells, chosen "custom formula" and entered =reference cell="reference value".  (see screenshot)  this should make the whole range of cells purple if cell G4 equals the letter M.  The problem is only the top-left cell in the range is changing color, not the whole range.

Also, I want to drag this block of cells down to repeat it, and for the conditional formatting to fill down appropriately (i.e. to reference cell G21 when I fill downwards and so on.) How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to lock it down with `$`

try:

```
=$G$4="M"
```

or:

```
=G$4="M"
```